# duda error en consulta Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Hola buenas tardes tengo esta duda con esta consulta SQL en esta base de datos porque me está causando un error, sera porque está con espacio FORMA DE PAGO?**

```
SELECT *
FROM PEDIDOS
WHERE FORMA DE PAGO = "TARJETA";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este caso, el nombre de columna al contener espacios, es inválido sintacticamente,  si mal no recuerdo, deberías usar corchetes, es decir, algo así: `WHERE [FORMA DE PAGO] = "TARJETA";`

Answer (score 2):

Rodee el elemento espaciado con corchetes:

```
[FORMA DE PAGO]
```

Luego abofetee al tipo que diseñó la base de datos.

[Respuesta original en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498251/query-a-table-that-has-spaces-in-its-name)